# “Cleaning up” meshes for unity: Necessary? Best practices?

Tags: mesh, export, normals, unity

I'm working on some low-poly assets in Blender with the goal of bringing them in as OBJs to Unity.

My question is about mesh preparation.

In edit mode, under the “Clean up” menu, I see:

[image]

Specifically:

1. Delete loose
2. Make planar faces
3. Split non-planar faces
4. Split concave faces
5. Fill holes

#### Questions:

1. When prepping meshes for Unity, should I be using any of the above options?
2. Should I triangulate my meshes in Blender before export (perhaps, using the triangulate modifier)?
3. In general, what process would you recommend I follow in order to get the best-looking mesh imported into Unity (and/or other gaming engines).

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not exactly a question if i read it right but more of an ask for advice. But i'll just give some anyway cause why not right. Anyway, i make the models for a game i'm working on, also low poly, what i usually do is just make the model, name it, remove doubles, check the normals, add the collision mesh, and make sure no modifiers are not yet applied.

Comment: Thanks Luka! I really appreciate the reply. That's great advice. Do you happen to know of a better place where I can ask this type of question? I am definitely looking for advice on best way to prep my meshes before export. Thanks again!!! :)

Comment: Don't know of anywhere else but the offical unity forums/Q&A site, but that place is full of 10 year olds and is hard to get good answers. Also, another thing, i find the model type FBX works good for my models. But this is all personal preference.

Comment: Thanks again for reply/help! I think I know what you mean about the Unity resources ... I suppose there's www.blenderartists.org, but I'm not sure if my skill level would fit in there (I'm still pretty new to Blender). I'm a huge fan of list servs... I'll have to look around. Thanks for tip on FBX! I'll check that out! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: blenderartists.org Could work, i sure they wouldn't mind a few questions if you can find the right section for them. Good luck with your model and game! :)

Comment: Thanks Luka!!!! Hope to see you around the net. Good luck in your game/3d/art endeavors as well. :)